# I need to calculate each students average grade

Tags: c++

```
/*This code creates two text files : Mokiniai.txt and Vidurkiai.txt
In Mokiniai.txt there are stored each students grades, in Vidurkiai there
should be calculated each students average grade*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n, k, isvisopazymiu, i, pazymiai;
    double vidurkis; //average grade
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Mokiniai.txt");
    cout << "parasykite kiek mokiniu yra" << endl; cin >> n; //how many students
    myfile << n << endl;
    cout << "parasykite kiek yra mokiniu pazymiu"; cin >> isvisopazymiu; // how many grades one student has
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        for (i = 1; i <= isvisopazymiu; i++) {
            cout << "Parasykite kokie yra mokiniu pazymiai "; cin >> pazymiai; // what are students grades
            myfile << " " << pazymiai;
        }
        myfile << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    myfile.open("Vidurkiai.txt"); //trying to calculate average students grades on different file
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        vidurkis = pazymiai / isvisopazymiu; //calculating students grades
        myfile << k << " " << vidurkis << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that: There is something wrong in vidurkiai.txt file, but I don't know what is wrong.

For example: first students grades are : 7 8 9 7 8, and average grade should be 7,8, but after coding it, in vidurkiai.txt file it shows, that average grade is 1.

Comment: This looks like your homework...

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @c650 Yes, it is my homework :D but still... I have some problems with it

Comment: How do you expect the following to work: `vidurkis = pazymiai / isvisopazymiu;` The reason I ask is these are all single values (and not arrays). How would this algorithm work with more than 1 student?? `pazymiai` and `isvisopazymiu` will contain whatever values you entered for the last student ignoring all previously entered data.

Comment: @drescherjm So you want to say, that students grades should be stored in arrays ?

Comment: Yes, you will need an array for this or write both files at the same time with only 1 `k` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it does not show the grades as expected is because you are not adding up the values.While taking the average over all the grades variable
'pazymiai' stores just the last entered variable. In order to complete the job you can use an 'array' to stores sum of grades in each array element .

```
cin>>pazymiai;
a[k]+=pazymiai;
```

where as while calculating grades use

```
 vidurkis = a[k] / isvisopazymiu;
```